# Pass input to modal boostrap and make confirmation modal

Tags: php, input, bootstrap-modal

I have some input number, I want to pass the value of input to a confirmation modal.
This is the modal I wanted as provided in the image
[image]

I want to pass 80($nilai variable) to modal that print $nilai and post it

```
<form action="<?= base_url('index.php/C_dosen/nilai/'.$jawab['id_tugas']) ?>" method="post">
    <input type="number" name="nilai" placeholder="Nilai" style="width:100px;" required oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Data Tidak Boleh Kosong')"
    oninput="this.setCustomValidity('')"  />
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?= $jawab['id_jawaban'] ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="tugas" value="<?= $jawab['id_tugas'] ?>"> 
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#edit<?= $jawab['id_jawaban']?>">
     <i class="ri-checkbox-line"> </i> Beri Nilai
    </button>
    </form>
```